# BigCommerce Express Checkout vs Nivo Slider Javascript

Tags: javascript, nivo-slider

I've implemented the Nivo Slider into my BigCommerce store. When I begin to check out with Express Checkout option it's causing an "Undefined: ExpressCheckout" error that will not allow the user to complete the checkout.

I reached out to BigCommerce support and they said that more than likely it's an issue with my slider and that I need to remove all instances of the javascript related to this slider.

Prior to doing this I wanted to see if anybody else ran into this issue with BigCommerce or whether the my javascript is incorrect?

Also, if you have any resources to debug or check my javascript that would be useful as well.

The link is as follows: http://teaetc.mybigcommerce.com/

1. Go to T Type > Green
2. Add product to cart
3. Proceed with Checkout
4. Try to check out as guest

You should receive the error following these steps.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I've recently run into this issue on my sandbox version of a site that was just handed to me: https://medicalsupplies.eppmo.com/checkout.php#

We cannot checkout either.  I'm attempting to remove all notations of any slider right now, but my boss said he's run across this before due to slider issues as well.

I know this issue is old, but I'll post any finds if I make any progress, because I found this thread by searching for the same issue.  Might help someone else out.

If anyone else has an idea on this, feel free to hop on my link and try to check out and let me know if you have any input.  Thanks :)